# Recursive Python Programming

Tags: python

All of the posts I can find on this only talk about recursion of subroutines within the program.

Is it possible to call the entire program again after the program has finished the first time round?

I need this for a client-server configuration so when the server has finished sharing information, it starts waiting for connections again from a different source.

I know it would be possible to do this with OOP quite easily, however I have already coded my server without it, and I feel getting this to work is an easier solution.

For example...

... Code that executes once ...

... Code that executes once ...

... Code that executes once ...

def placeholder():

... Code in the subroutine ...

def placeholdertwo():

... Code in the subroutine ...

placeholder()

placeholdertwo()

** The WHOLE program runs again from the first 'code that executes once' **

Comment: Put the whole "program" into one function and call it over and over again, without calling the whole "program". I'm not saying that is the only way to do it, but it is the only recommended way to do it ;)

Comment: Wrap the whole program into one function, and just have: while True: runProgram()

Comment: Why don't you make a "master" routine that listens for incoming connections, and spawns a thread with a "child" routine that handles the request while the master still listens for other requests? in this way you can respond to two  incoming requests without waiting for the program to finish (long story short: wrap "the program" in a function :) ). But this is not recursivness...